# How to blacklist pwm_backlight?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, backlight

I want to control PWM from sysfs. I have `/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0` and `cat npwm` gives `1`. However, when I try to `echo 0 >> export` I am given with `Device or resource busy`. I checked `cat /sys/kernel/debug/pwm` and it showed me that this PWM is held by `pwm_backlight` (`pwm-0 (pwm_backlight): requested period ...`).

I tried `rmmod pwm_backlight` but the module does not exist.

I tried `rmmod backlight` but the module is built-in.

I tried `initcall_blacklist=backlight_class_init` kernel cmdline but then there were no graphics on HDMI (the only video output, system was booted)

I also tried `modprobe.blacklist=backlight` and `backlight.blacklist=yes` with no success.

Is there a way to get rid of `pwm_backlight` without recompiling the Kernel?

Btw, I am absolutely sure that I want to controls this (this particular) PWM through sysfs :-)

Btw2, This is Intel platform, no device trees etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was caused by `i915` module. PWM released after `rmmod i915`. I checked BIOS/UEFI setup (IGD settings) and found something related to backlight for MIPI/DSI panel. I completely disabled panel support and then the PWM was never held by `i915` again.